# Defining terms in the specifications of a non-inferiority test

Tags: non-inferiority

We wish to test the hypothesis that a treatment has efficacy $\pi_t$ that is non-inferior to control $\pi_c$.

What do we call the non-inferiority boundary, call this $\pi_{t0}$, the threshold given by the non-inferiority margin and $\pi_c$. Also, is the non-inferiority margin calculated as $\pi_c - \pi_{t0}$ or $\pi_{t0}-\pi_c$?

Comment: Regarding your second question: Assuming that higher efficacy is better, you would specify the null hypothesis of non-inferiority as $H_0:\pi_t - \pi_c\leq \delta$ with $\delta$ being the non-inferiority margin ($\delta <0$). So the non-inferiority margin is specified in terms of the difference between the efficacies.